# how to place last div into right top corner of parent div? (css)

Tags: html, css

Can I somehow use CSS to place the `block2` in **top right corner** of `block1`?

---

#### Context :

- `block2` must be the (very) last inside HTML code of `block1` or it could be placed after `block1`. I can't make it the first element in `block1`.
- Within `block1` there could be `<p>`, images, text and it is beyond my control to know what and how many.
- Also I need the `block2` to flow.

---

#### Code :

```css
.block1 {
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.block2 {
    color: blue;
    width: 70px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='block1'>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text2</p>
    <div class='block2'>block2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```css
.block1 {
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
}

.block2 {
    color: blue;
    width: 70px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block1'>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text2</p>
  <div class='block2'>block2</div>
</div>
```

Should do it. Assuming you don't need it to flow.

Comment: excuse me but what does it mean? `you dont need it to flow`

Comment: He means using absolute positioning or hard coding the position of the element inside of block 1. Usually you try to avoid this solution if possible but in some situations it's what you have to do.

Comment: +1 for a useful answer, but i needed something a little different, i needed block2 to be middle/center aligned on the top right corner of block1 .. http://jsfiddle.net/farinspace/jywqk/

Comment: This is close, but I'm trying to do something similar and need the content from block one to wrap around block two.

Comment: This solution places the div in the top right of the page, not the parent div

Answer (score 18):

You can simply add a right float to .block2 element and place it in the first position (this is very important).

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .block1 {
            color: red;
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        .block2 {
            color: blue;
            width: 70px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            position: relative;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='block1'>
        <div class='block2'>block2</div>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text2</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Regards...

Comment: what if i cannot place it in first position, because it is coming from a database server

Comment: The important stuff here is 

position: relative;
float: right;

Then to make it top align just put:

 margin-top:auto;

Answer (score 4):

```
 <div class='block1'>
    <p  style="float:left">text</p>
    <div class='block2' style="float:right">block2</div>
    <p  style="float:left; clear:left">text2</p>

 </div>
```

You can `clear:both` or `clear:left` depending on the exact context.
Also, you will have to play around with `width` to get it to work correctly...

Comment: @xander can I work on block1 properties itself instead of what ever inside. The content comes from WordPress so I am not sure how to cover everything within block1 in css

Comment: @Radek Is there always one (1) div inside of "block1" if so you could target through CSS selector `div.block1 div` or if `div.block1`'s child has a class then `div.block1 div.block2 { float:right; }` should do the trick along with `div.block1 p { float:left; clear:left }`

Comment: @xander: I like your solution the best but I am struggling to implement it in on this page http://vk.onalllevels.com/about/limor I cannot tell what elements are going to be inside `<div class="format_text">`

Comment: if it helps I can move `<div class='block2'>block2</DIV>` after definition of block1 in html

Comment: That would be best. to move it (`div.block2`) after the first `<p>` tag that is floated left. Everything else can "flow" after them...

Comment: I cannot move block2 within block1. Block2 could be the last thing in block1 or after block1 completely.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add another wrapping div "block3" you could do something like this.

```
 <html>
      <head>
      <style type="text/css">
      .block1 {color:red;width:120px;border:1px solid green; height: 100px;}
      .block3 {float:left; width:10px;}
      .block2 {color:blue;width:70px;border:2px solid black;position:relative;float:right;}
      </style>
      </head>

    <body>
    <div class='block1'>

        <div class='block3'>
            <p>text1</p>
            <p>text2</p>
        </div>

        <div class='block2'>block2</DIV>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't think I can wrap it in block3 :-(

Answer (score 1):

Displaying left middle and right of there parents. If you have more then 3 elements then use nth-child() for them.

[image]

HTML sample:

```
<body>
    <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li><a  id="btn-tab-business" class="btn-tab nav-tab-selected"  onclick="openTab('business','btn-tab-business')"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Business</a></li>
        <li><a  id="btn-tab-expertise" class="btn-tab" onclick="openTab('expertise', 'btn-tab-expertise')"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Expertise</a></li>
        <li><a  id="btn-tab-quality" class="btn-tab" onclick="openTab('quality', 'btn-tab-quality')"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Quality</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS sample:

```
.nav-tabs{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.nav-tabs li {
  display: inline-block;  
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-tabs li:first-child{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav-tabs li:last-child{
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.nav-tabs li:nth-child(2){
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```