# Aligning a <p> tag in top right corner of <textarea>?

Tags: html, css

I have a small textarea on my page. With it, I have a `<p>` tag that says "HTML". What I want to do is align that `<p>` tag to the top right corner of the textarea, so users will know that this textarea shows HTML code. However, all my attempts have placed the `<p>` tag in the top right corner of the page.

```
<div id="mycode">
   <p id="htmltag">HTML</p>
   <textarea id="htmlcode" style="background-color: #1e1e1e; color: #ffff66;">
      This is my HTML code
   </textarea>
</div>
```

I am now also willing to use Javascript, but no Jquery.

Comment: You want the `p` element to appear within the area of the `textarea`?

Comment: Yes, I want the p element to appear in the top-right corner of the textarea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to place last div into right top corner of parent div? (css)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842368/how-to-place-last-div-into-right-top-corner-of-parent-div-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly simple to do. Just set your wrapper to be relatively positioned, then you can absolutely position your label inside the wrapper.

As @Optimae suggested, here is some CSS which also prevents the html code from being obscured by your label.

```css
#mycode {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* Allow horizontal resize */
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
}

#htmltag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#htmlcode {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1.2em);
  margin-top: 1.2em; /* prevents the code from going behind the label */
  outline: none; /* Prevents blue outline when focused */
}
```

```html
<div id="mycode">
   <p id="htmltag">HTML</p>
   <textarea id="htmlcode">
      This is my HTML code
      
      With some more
      text
      to 
      force 
      scrolling
   </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is the solution, wouldn't it be more beneficial to the OP to have the HTML text outside the `textarea` and styled to look the same with 0 margins? That way users can fully utilise the `textarea` without the HTML text covering their code when they hit the end of the line.

Comment: Fails to take user resizable `textarea`s into account.

Comment: I must admit this is a very nice solution, although it is more of a shortcut to doing what I needed. However, is there a way to do something like this with the p tag above the textarea while still preventing the code from going behind the label?

Comment: @IamGuest, just with CSS, I don't believe there is. With some JavaScript it could be possible to insert a linebreak at the right place to prevent the issue.

Comment: Also, what you have done in the above code could easily have been accomplished with CSS text-align, as shown by Đức Nguyễn.

Comment: My answer was posted before that other answer, and his solution had not occurred to me.

Comment: Also, when you click the textarea it is clearly visible to the user that the label is not at the top-right corner of the textarea.

Comment: @Ouroborus, vertical resizing works as expected now. I'm unsure if horizontal resizing is possible while avoiding JavaScript.

Comment: @Gerrit0 Of course it's possible. The other valid solutions handle it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position:absolute`, right and top on the `p` tag. Then remove browser specific margins and padding. To have it adjust to the textbox size, use javascript to set the width dynamically. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENvjwj)

```js
document.getElementById('mycode').style.width = document.getElementById('htmlcode').getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
```

```css
#mycode {
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
}
#htmltag {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  color: red;
  z-index:1;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mycode">
     <p id="htmltag">HTML</p>
     <textarea id="htmlcode" style="background-color: #1e1e1e; color: #ffff66;">
      This is my HTML code
   </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would use Javascript for this when you could use just a bit more CSS and have something that handles page resizes correctly.

Comment: This is ok, however, when a user resizes the textbox the p tag no longer remains in the top right corner, which looks very odd.

Answer (score 0):

you need a relative parent to be used as reference for an absolute child.

This parent should hold label(you use p) and textarea together and shrink on it.

basicly it can be done like this:

```css
#mycode {
  position: relative;
  /* be reference for positionning clidren*/
  display: table;
  /* shrinks/expands with content could be also inline-block/table/flex*/
}
#htmltag {
  margin: 0;
  right: 1.2em;
  /* stay away from scrollbar*/
  position: absolute;
  color: gray;
}
textarea {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #ffff66;
  padding-top: 1.2em;/* clear some space to show the label*/
```

```html
<div id="mycode">
  <label for="htmlcode" id="htmltag">HTML</label>
  <textarea id="htmlcode" placeholder="HTML">
    This is my HTML code, resize me boxe
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @IamGuest no it does not. for this you need javascript.