# Put <h1> tag in a corner

Tags: html, css

So I want to put a h1 tag in the bottom right corner. What I have currently is below; however, this is very tedious and I want it to always be in the corner. Currently the way I am doing it is based off of my computer's screen, but if someone uses a computer with a different size screen then the tag will not be in the right place. Would there be any other way I could do this so that the tag would be in the same place for all size monitors?

```css
.subH {
  font-family: Sedgwick Ave Display;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding-top: 505px;
  padding-left: 1170px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='subH'>Created by Hybrid Alpaca Game Studios</h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to place last div into right top corner of parent div? (css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842368/how-to-place-last-div-into-right-top-corner-of-parent-div-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS to keep element at "fixed" position on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576342/css-to-keep-element-at-fixed-position-on-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: fixed`

**Example:**

```
h1 {
position: fixed;
bottom 6px;
left: 6px;
}
```

Comment: For reference, see [fixed positioning @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning).