# Fixing div in top right corner of another scrollable div

Tags: javascript, css

I need to fix a div in the top-right corner of another div. The parent div gets updated with new content and is scrollable.

I tried following some of the answers given to [how to place last div into right top corner of parent div? (css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842368/how-to-place-last-div-into-right-top-corner-of-parent-div-css/2842377#2842377) and played around a little, but it always scrolls out of view when I scroll the parent div. How can I make sure it stays there?

This is the closest I've gotten to what I need. But it scrolls out of view if I scroll the parent div.

```css
.A {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.B {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div className="A">
        <b>SOME TEXT</b>
        <div className="B">
            <b>SOME OTHER TEXT</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`

Comment: @MohammadFaisal, by doing that, the child div just moves to the bottom, and the scrolling issue is still there.

Comment: will you please share the screenshot of the output of your code.

Comment: position:fixed for class B will do.

Comment: Your question is so unclear. What is your parent div? Which portion you want to be sticked on top? Which portion is scrollble?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to solve may got some help

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="A">
        <b>SOME TEXT</b>
    </div>
    <div class="B">
      <b>SOME OTHER TEXT</b>
    </div>
</div>

.A {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 530px;
}

.B {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
.parent{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: This will help you to create scrolling and fixing to top even if this is block is just a part of your application. using position fixed is relative to your whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Class A needs position :relative and Class B position : fixed

```
.A {
  position: relative;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.B {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-wildflower-0g8gc)

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is an option, you could adjust your layout and styles like:

```
<div>
    <div className="A">
        <b>SOME TEXT</b>
        <div className="B">
           <div className="C">
             <b>SOME OTHER TEXT</b>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.A {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.B {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  height: {_ => _.elementAScrollHeight};
}
.C {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Where elementAScrollHeight scroll height is the scroll height of  gotten by JS (e.g. in react it's done easily using refs).

Answer (score -1):

Figured out a way to do it, using z-index:

```css
.A {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.B {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="A">
        <b>SOME TEXT</b>
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        <b>SOME OTHER TEXT</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution has nothing to do with z-index, your div got aligned top right because your div `.B` is not anymore in `.A`, that has absolute positionning, but in `.parent`, that has static positionning.